# devstack fails with error markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment

Tags: pip, openstack, devstack

I've created a virtualbox image with ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop version and followed the steps with a simple minimal local.conf: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/index.html

The problem is that `stack.sh` fails with this output:

```
+ inc/python:pip_install:359:   sudo -H http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= PIP_FIND_LINKS= SETUPTOOLS_SYS_PATH_TECHNIQUE=rewrite /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install -c /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt systemd-python
Ignoring asyncio: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring asyncio: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring dnspython3: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring dnspython3: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring mypy: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring mypy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring jeepney: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring jeepney: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring SecretStorage: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring SecretStorage: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring Django: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring Django: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring cmd2: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring cmd2: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring typed-ast: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring typed-ast: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Requirement already satisfied: systemd-python===234 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -c /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt (line 417))
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've already upgraded the pip to version 18.0 with `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` from `stack` user and executed again the `stack.sh` script and fails again with same error:

```
...
Collecting virtualenv===16.0.0 (from -c /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt (line 532))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/30/96a02b2287098b23b875bc8c2f58071c35d2efe84f747b64d523721dc2b5/virtualenv-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Found existing installation: virtualenv 16.0.0
    Uninstalling virtualenv-16.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled virtualenv-16.0.0
Successfully installed virtualenv-16.0.0
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've upgraded pip with the command above and it has displayed success, but after running again `stack.sh` the version is back again:

```
pip -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Then I've upgraded again with: `sudo easy_install -U pip`
and it displayed successfully upgraded and finally I've tried with this command: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`

And `pip -V` displays after reinstall:

`pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

but `stack.sh` still fails with the same output error. 
Then it seems like stack.sh downgrade pip for some reasons.

Comment: The command doesn't fail. It just tells you that `systemd-python` is already installed. Check the exit code of the install command and don't abort the script. The info lines about the markers are also harmless; they just notify you that some dependencies won't be installed because you're using Python 2.

Comment: @hoefling actuall `stack.sh` failed with exit `127`

Comment: the error 127 it is caused because a file is not found, could this be a bug? `+ inc/python:pip_install:359               :   env http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= PIP_FIND_LINKS= SETUPTOOLS_SYS_PATH_TECHNIQUE=rewrite /opt/stack/requirements/.venv/bin/pip install -c /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt -U pbr
env: ‘/opt/stack/requirements/.venv/bin/pip’: No such file or directory
+ inc/python:pip_install:1                 :   exit_trap
+ ./stack.sh:exit_trap:515                 :   local r=127
`

Comment: This is a different command than the one in the question. This one fails because `/opt/stack/requirements/.venv/bin/pip` is not found; probably the venv was not created.

Comment: yes you are right but I've realized now the error code was not related to the "warnings" messages in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have the same issue.
upgrade pip doesn't work for me, but the solution is

```
cd ~/devstack/tools/
```

and then edit 
`sudo gedit cap-pip.txt`
this file contains `pip!=8,<10`
change this for `pip!=18,<20`